# VBA SQL Query only returns numeric values

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

I have a program designed to re-transcribe a text file into MS Excel using a VBA macro with an SQL query using ADODB.

The text file is itself an extract from a database from another department(and is presented as a comma separated table in the text file).

Anyway, I have a column ('Group' below) filed with either 'Z4' or '50'. These are the only two types of input for said column.

Until today, the query returned both values. Now, I only get '50'. The cells where 'Z4' ought to appear are empty.

Code is below:

```vb
Sub TextReader()
    'Text reader

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Error Management
    On Error Resume Next

    '--------- Connection -------------------------------
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim str As String

    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    cnn.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"            '
    cnn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""text; HDR=YES; FMT=Delimited;"""

    'Open Connection
    cnn.Open

    'ADODB record
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    'cleanup
    Sheets("Cost").Cells.Clear

    'SQL String
    str = "select Group from ZR46.txt "

    'Get the values
    With rs
        .ActiveConnection = cnn
        .Open str
        Sheets("Cost").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
        .Close
    End With

    'Close
    cnn.Close

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The text file (not exactly that, but modified because it's private data):

```
,Article,Designation,Price,Strat,Group,Provis,
,123456789,BODY,706§09,PD,Z4,COND,
,897654321,BONNET,1§456§15,PD,Z4,COND,
,123789456,STEM,102§06,PD,50,COND,
```

Comment: Note that `On Error Resume Next` is **no error management** at all! This just hides *all* error messages but the errors still occur you just cannot see their messages. If you don't see the error you cannot fix it, if you cannot fix it your code cannot work. Remove that line and tell which errors you get and where. •  If you are interested in a good guide for error handling, read [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Comment: Is the file in the same format? I.e. with the same separator and encoding, etc.?

Comment: You should include `IMEX=1` in your connection string but that's still no guarantee that you will get all the data from a column with mixed data types in it (databases don't allow that so things like ADO don't generally cope well with it)

Comment: Pᴇʜ, I've tried removing it at first, but it doesn't change anything, I've no error in the code.

tk78, The file with the macro is an .xlsm Excel file, the file with the data is a .txt file. This has worked fine for a couple of months...Today is a Monday
     
Rory, Tried it but it didn't work

Comment: str = "select   '' & Group as strGroup from ZR46.txt "  should force the column to text  (That's two single quotes not a speech mark)  which might help?

Comment: @HarassedDad, Tried that as well, it modifies the '50' to a string, but I'm still not getting the 'Z4'. It does seem to show that the column is considered to be filled with Numeric values even though the first lines feature 'Z4'. PS: funny user name ☺

Comment: Can you show a small extract of how the data is formatted in the text file?  Just edit the question to add it

Comment: @Dave, I included a sample of the data. I found a workaround, which is to replace  `,50,` in the text file with `,'50,` . Not pretty but I works. I still don't understand why it won't return my non numeric values though. I mean if this were a development stage, then I would say 'It doesn't work that way'. But after 2 months of working without fail, it suddenly decides 'Nope, not this time !!'....

Comment: Like I said, it's an issue with mixed data types. I'd guess in previous versions that data had some `Z4` values in the first few rows, whereas this time it didn't.

Comment: @Rory, I get that, I just don't understand the why of it. I checked to make sure a `Z4` was among the first columns. Maybe the ADODB query doesn't 'read' the data in a linear way ?

Comment: Your `Group` is a mixed format, it is `Z4` and `50`, ADO will guess using the first 8 rows if you don't specify anything in your connection string. Usually, if it was a spreadsheet you can sort it descending and it will guarantee that ADO will import it as text only, but in your case you have can use `HDR=No` and `IMEX=1` which in that case your headers will be considered the first row and they are all text